# angular doesn't update component

Tags: angular

I have a simple view like this

```
<div *ngIf = "user$ | async as user ">
  <app-user-portfolio-edit [user]="user"></app-user-portfolio-edit>
</div>
```

the `user$` comes from

```
this.user$ = this.store.select( state => {
  const userToEdit = state.user.userToEdit;
  console.log('selecting user ', userToEdit);
  return userToEdit;
});
```

When I dispatch an action and update the `userToEdit` I see the the `select` call fires, and it is returning a new user.

But my component doesn't get the new user. I have a property setter to listen to the changes, which never fires after the first call.

Comment: Where is placed "this.user$ = ...." ?

Comment: Can you show us your component child please (.ts)